# modify session variable (shopping cart)

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, session-variables

Session For products

```
$product = array(array('name'=>$resname, 'code'=>$product_code, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$resprice, 'sizes'=>$sizes ,'colourcode'=>$colourcode , 'availability'=>$availability));
$_SESSION["products"] = $product;

    name="product1";
    code="123";
    ...
    availability=1;
```

now i want to modify **availability** for specific product in session using **for each loop only**

```
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm){ 
$cart_itm["code"];
$cart_itm["availability"];
//code to  modify availability for current product  
}
```

Comment: did you used my answer? why downvote?

Comment: NO, i didn't downvote. jst nw i saw and voted. even my question is downvoted by someone

Comment: Don't know someone given without giving proper reason. How we can know/correct our answer?

Comment: may be they will get some reputation or badge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it you are looking for?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $product = array(array('name'=>'resname', 'code'=>'product_code', 'qty'=>'product_qty', 'price'=>'resprice', 'sizes'=>'sizes' ,'colourcode'=>'colourcode' , 'availability'=>'availability'));
    $newProduct=$product;// new step
    $_SESSION["products"] = $newProduct;


    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm){ 
    $newProduct[0]["availability"]='modifiedavailability';
    }

   //or To all Keys

   // foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm => $value){ 
    //$cart_itm["code"];
    //$newProduct[$cart_itm]["availability"]='modavaila';
   //}
    $_SESSION["products"] = $newProduct;
    print_r($_SESSION["products"]);
?>
```

Comment: $product variable is in another php file. i want to change using Session.
$_SESSION["products"][$cart_itm]["availability"]=0;
is it ok?

Comment: then you can add one step, $newProduct edited in my post. please check

Comment: yup this is also will works

Comment: will it replace old one or it is again building all the products.
$_SESSION["products"][$cart_itm]["availability"]=0; works?

Comment: If you want to replace exist one you can use it, Its working fine $_SESSION["products"][$cart_itm]["availability"]